# Include a library in cmake_ament package

Tags: c++, cmake, include, ros2

Taking this example from [ROS2 official documentation](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Writing-A-Simple-Cpp-Publisher-And-Subscriber.html), i want to add a library to one of the cmake_ament build packages.

In the example, they already included the string library

`#include std_msgs/msg/string.hpp`

for :

`auto message = std_msgs::msg::String();`

`//and other manipulations`

My task is to add a similar existing library to manipulate `UInt64` types. I found it [here](http://wiki.ros.org/std_msgs).

My lazy try was to `#include std_msgs/msg/string.hpp` mimicking the example, after building, i got the error :

```
fatal error: std_msgs/msg/uint64.msg: No such file or directory
   22 | #include "std_msgs/msg/uint64.msg"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

So, i'm asking for working ways to manage it.

My CmakeLists.txt contains :

```
find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)
ament_target_dependencies(talker rclcpp std_msgs)
ament_target_dependencies(listener rclcpp std_msgs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.msg is wrong. You have to use #include "std_msgs/msg/uint64.hpp" or "std_msgs/msg/uint64.h"